# Attention on top of LSTM Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm, attention-model

I was training an LSTM Model using Keras and wanted to add Attention on top of it. I am new to Keras, and Attention. From link [How to add an attention mechanism in keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42918446/how-to-add-an-attention-mechanism-in-keras) I learnt how I could add attention over my LSTM Layer and made a model like this

```python
print('Defining a Simple Keras Model...')
lstm_model=Sequential()  # or Graph 
lstm_model.add(Embedding(output_dim=300,input_dim=n_symbols,mask_zero=True,
                    weights=[embedding_weights],input_length=input_length))  

# Adding Input Length
lstm_model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(300)))
lstm_model.add(Dropout(0.3))
lstm_model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))

# compute importance for each step
attention=Dense(1, activation='tanh')
attention=Flatten()
attention=Activation('softmax')
attention=RepeatVector(64)
attention=Permute([2, 1])


sent_representation=keras.layers.Add()([lstm_model,attention])
sent_representation=Lambda(lambda xin: K.sum(xin, axis=-2),output_shape=(64))(sent_representation)

sent_representation.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))

rms_prop=RMSprop(lr=0.001,rho=0.9,epsilon=None,decay=0.0)
adam = Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0, amsgrad=False)
print('Compiling the Model...')
sent_representation.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer=adam,metrics=['accuracy'])
          #class_mode='binary')

earlyStopping=EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',min_delta=0,patience=0,
                                    verbose=0,mode='auto')

print("Train...")
sent_representation.fit(X_train, y_train,batch_size=batch_size,nb_epoch=20,
          validation_data=(X_test,y_test),callbacks=[earlyStopping])
```

The output will be a sentiment analysis of 0/1. For that I added a

```python
 sent_representation.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
```

for it to give a binary result.

This is the error we are getting on running the code:

```python
ERROR:
  File "<ipython-input-6-50a1a221497d>", line 18, in <module>
    sent_representation=keras.layers.Add()([lstm_model,attention])

  File "C:\Users\DuttaHritwik\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 575, in __call__
    self.assert_input_compatibility(inputs)

  File "C:\Users\DuttaHritwik\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 448, in assert_input_compatibility
    str(inputs) + '. All inputs to the layer '

ValueError: Layer add_1 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'keras.models.Sequential'>. Full input: [<keras.models.Sequential object at 0x00000220B565ED30>, <keras.layers.core.Permute object at 0x00000220FE853978>]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.
```

Can you have a look and tell us what we are doing wrong here?

Comment: here a simple way to add attention: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62949137/10375049

Answer (score 2):

`keras.layers.Add()` takes tensors, so at

`sent_representation=keras.layers.Add()([lstm_model,attention])`

you're passing a sequential model as input and are getting an error.
Change your initial layers from using the Sequential model to using the functional api.

```
lstm_section = Embedding(output_dim=300,input_dim=n_symbols,mask_zero=True, weights=[embedding_weights],input_length=input_length)( input )
lstm_section = Bidirectional(LSTM(300)) ( lstm_section )
lstm_section = Dropout(0.3)( lstm_section ) 
lstm_section = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')( lstm_section )
```

`lstm_section` is a tensor that can then replace `lstm_model` in your Add() call.

Since you're using the functional API rather than Sequential, you'll also need to create the model, using
`your_model = keras.models.Model( inputs, sent_representation )`

Also worth noting that the attention model in the link you gave multiplies rather than adds, so might be worth using `keras.layers.Multiply()`.

**Edit**

Just noticed that your attention section also isn't building a graph since you're not passing each layer into the next one. It should be:

```
attention=Dense(1, activation='tanh')( lstm_section )
attention=Flatten()( attention )
attention=Activation('softmax')( attention )
attention=RepeatVector(64)( attention )
attention=Permute([2, 1])( attention )
```

Comment: I tried doing this
`sent_representation=Add()([lstm_section, attention])`
but this error comes out:

    `Layer add_3 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'keras.layers.core.Permute'>. Full input: [<keras.layers.core.Permute object at 0x000001D0B2E28048>, <keras.layers.core.Permute object at 0x000001D0B2E28048>]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.`

Since it seems one is tensor other is not, I also tried:
`sent_representation=Add()([lstm_section, lstm_section])`
`sent_representation=Add()([attention, attention])`

The error persists.

Comment: Edited answer to address that issue

Comment: This is what I am getting now :
`ValueError: Layer add_8 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'keras.layers.core.Dense'>. Full input: [<keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x000001D0BA937E80>, <keras.layers.core.Permute object at 0x000001D0B4B85CC0>]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.`

Comment: Code works for me after I implemented the changes. Could you edit your original post and add the current state of your code?