# BI LSTM with attention layer in python for text classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, nlp

I want to apply this method to implement Bi-LSTM with attention. The method is discussed here: [Bi-LSTM Attention model in Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52867069/bi-lstm-attention-model-in-keras)

I get the following error:
`'module' object is not callable`

It can not apply multiply in this line:
`sent_representation = merge([lstm, attention], mode='mul')`

```py
from keras.layers import merge
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Concatenate, Dense, Input, LSTM, Embedding, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Permute, RepeatVector
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Bidirectional

inp =Input(shape=(maxlen,), dtype='float32')
x = Embedding(max_features, embed_size, weights=[emb_matrix])(inp)
lstm = Bidirectional(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True), name="bi_lstm_0")(x)

attention = Dense(1, activation='tanh')(lstm)
attention = Flatten()(attention)
attention = Activation('softmax')(attention)
attention = RepeatVector(max_features*2)(attention)
attention = Permute([2,1])(attention)

sent_representation = merge([lstm, attention], mode='mul')
sent_representation = Lambda(lambda xin: K.sum(xin, axis=1))(sent_representation)

output = Dense(3, activation="softmax")(sent_representation)
```

Comment: I removed the code that was irrelevant to the question. In the original code, you did the projecting with softmax twice, it would not learn like that.

Comment: thank you. can you please help me to solve my issue. I'm new to nlp and deep learning, im working on this attention for days and every time I get new error.

Comment: because at the end I need 3 label, I can not use sigmoid or.. can you please help me?

Comment: But you are already using softmax normalization with 3 labels. What is the problem then?

Comment: that is attention layer.

Answer (score 0):

In Keras, [`merge`](https://keras.io/api/layers/merging_layers/) is a module that contains layers that implement various ways of merging outputs of other layers. You need to select a method that you want to use to merge the states.

In this particular case, you want to [concatenate](https://keras.io/api/layers/merging_layers/concatenate/) the outputs.

Comment: Can you please tell me, how can I add concatenate ?

Comment: It is `tensorflow.keras.layers.Concatenate`. You already imported it.

Comment: I tried  but the error:  Failed to convert object of type <class 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers.merge.Concatenate'> to Tensor. Contents: <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.merge.Concatenate object at 0x7f74b7b1f358>. Consider casting elements to a supported type.